# Ruby run shell command not working (for facebook app)

Tags: ruby, facebook, shell, android-activity, command

I am trying to run a system call which will post an activity to a user on facebook.
When I run this on the command line, everything works fine but on my RoR controller, I don't get any result. I have all the permissions required to post an activity for a user and I've already tried using system(), backticks(`), exec() and %x but still no luck.
Any idea on this? here's my code:

```
post = "curl -F 'access_token=#{session[:access_token]}' -F 'achievement=https://example.com/main/fbobject' 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/app_fb:send'"
system(post)
```

Comment: Can you post the result of the `curl` command?(by rendering it or something)? Also, do you run the RoR server on your own computer or on a server? If you run it on a server, maybe you don't have permissions to run shell commands on that machine.

Comment: `system` only returns true, false or nil, try backticks and print out the result. Don't use `exec` (http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine now. For references, here's the solution.
On the server settings under directives, 
I have:

```
 SetEnv PATH /usr/local/bin
 SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib
```

and added:

```
 SetEnv PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/
 SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib:/usr/bin/lib
```

I've included `:/usr/bin/` and `:/usr/bin/lib` since curl command is located there.